# Build a dataframe conditioned to time

Tags: r, loops, time-complexity, systemtime

I am trying to build a data frame named 'df' that registers the time stamp when each row was entered. 'df' should have a unique column:

The data I want to input in 'df' is from data frame 'a', column 'textid':

```
str(a$textid)
```

> chr [1:262] "xxxxx yyy" ...

'a' is composed as:

```
str(a)
```

> 'data.frame':  262 obs. of  3 variables:
>    $ V1    : chr  "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" ...
>    $ textid: chr "xxxxx yyyy" ...
>    $ limit : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...

```
dput(droplevels(head(a)))
```

> structure(list(V1 = c("Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
>   "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
>   "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
>   "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
>   "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
>   "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ"
>   ), textid = c("xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy" 
>   ), limit = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("V1", 
>   "textid", "limit"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

I need a condition for time. Every row has to be input if:

```
if(as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 11 & as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 17 != 0)
```

After the row is entered there should be a loop that should wait for the next time that Sys.Time() (coerced as an integer value) matches that condition.

For that I have built this code:

```
df <- c(NA)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(a), nrow = nrow(a)))


i=1

while(i <= nrow(a)) {
    repeat {
        if (as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 11 & as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 17 != 0) {
            break
        } else {
            df[i,]<- paste(Sys.time(),a$textid[i])
            i=i+1
        }
    }
}
```

Unsuccesfully I am obtaining al df's rows at the same time with the same time stamp.

```
str(df)
```

> 'data.frame':  2982 obs. of  1 variable:
>    $ c(NA): chr  "2017-07-10 13:14:58 xxxxx yyy" ...

Then I have tried

```
i=1 
while(i<=nrow(ids) & as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 11 == 0 & as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 17 == 0) {
    df[i,]<-paste(Sys.time(),a$textid[i]) 
    i=1+i
}
```

but I get an empty 'df'.

Finnally I am trying:

```
i=1
df<-as.data.frame(c(NA))
repeat{
    if(as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 11 & as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 17 == 0{
        df[i,]<-paste(Sys.time(),a$textid[i])
        i=1+i
    }
  if(i>nrow(ids)){
    break
  }
}
```

But 'a's´ rows keep entering at the same time to 'df' and do not loop looking for the next condition in time that matches before entering each row.

```
dput(droplevels(head(df)))
```

> structure(list(`c(NA)` = c("2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxx yyyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxxx yyy"
>   )), .Names = "c(NA)", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

As you can see the time is the same for every row. What I am trying to get is something like:

> structure(list(`c(NA)` = c("2017-07-11 16:30:46 xxxx yyyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:31:12 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:31:51 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:33:33 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:33:35 xxxxx yyy", 
>   "2017-07-11 16:36:28 xxxxx yyy"
>   )), .Names = "c(NA)", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Your line `df[i,]< paste(Sys.time(),a$textid[i])i=i+1` has a couple syntax errors: You probably mean ` <- ` for assignment, not `<` for "less than", and you should put `i = i + 1` on it's own line. The `repeat` is not needed, just `while` is enough, and then you can get rid of the `break` as well. If you need more help, please make your example reproducible by sharing a little sample of `a` that we can run on - just a few rows. Also, you do not show any initialization of `df`, but that is also needed.

Comment: Thanks, it was a syntax error here, I already corrected it, but in my RStudio Script the code is correct and I have the problem I am exposing in the question.

Comment: Okay, that takes care of the first sentence of my comment. Please move on to the rest, especially the third sentence: *If you need more help, please make your example reproducible by sharing a little sample of `a` that we can run on - just a few rows.* Though I do think the second sentence is valuable as well.

Comment: I provided the information by editing the question and i also changed the code to: i=1
while(i<=nrow(ids) & 
      as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 11 == 0 & 
      as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 17 == 0)
  {
  df[i,]<-paste(Sys.time(),a$textid[i])
  i=1+i
}. I am getting the tree columns of data frame 'a' in one column.

Comment: Can you edit that new code into your question (replacing the old code)? It's hard to read in the comment. Also can you share a small sample of `a`? Use `dput(droplevels(head(a)))` so it is copy/pasteable.

Comment: I did, I included the small samples, other codes I have thought and their results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148942/discussion-between-anitasp-and-gregor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite get what you really need.
Here are my two guesses:

1. You want to block code execution for each row insertion until your time criterion is met again, so you can do some time critical code execution. Then you need `Sys.sleep()` to halt your code execution.

   ```
   a <- structure(list(V1 = c("Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" ), textid = c("xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy" ), limit = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("V1", "textid", "limit"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

   #Using your example code:
   df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(NA, nrow(a)))
   i <- 1
   while(i <= nrow(a)) {
       if (as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 11 & as.integer(Sys.time()) %% 17 != 0) {
           #Sleep to reduce CPU occupation.
           Sys.sleep(0.5)
       } else {
           df[i,]<- paste(Sys.time(),a$textid[i])
           ###############################
           # Do something time critical. #
           ###############################
           i <- i + 1
           #Blocking for 1 second, thus as.integer(Sys.time()) will
           #be garantied to be different.
           Sys.sleep(1)
       }
   }

   df
   #                             V1
   #1 2017-07-13 02:43:48 xxxxx yyy
   #2 2017-07-13 02:43:54 xxxxx yyy
   #3 2017-07-13 02:43:59 xxxxx yyy
   #4 2017-07-13 02:44:10 xxxxx yyy
   #5 2017-07-13 02:44:11 xxxxx yyy
   #6 2017-07-13 02:44:21 xxxxx yyy
   ```
2. You simply need the filled data frame starting from the current system time.

   ```
   a <- structure(list(V1 = c("Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" ), textid = c("xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy" ), limit = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("V1", "textid", "limit"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

   #Using your example code:
   df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(NA, nrow(a)))
   i <- 1
   t <- Sys.time()
   while(i <= nrow(a)) {
       if (!(as.integer(t) %% 11 & as.integer(t) %% 17 != 0)) {
           df[i,]<- paste(t,a$textid[i])
           i <- i + 1
       }
       t <- t + 1
   }

   df
   #                             V1
   #1 2017-07-13 02:43:48 xxxxx yyy
   #2 2017-07-13 02:43:54 xxxxx yyy
   #3 2017-07-13 02:43:59 xxxxx yyy
   #4 2017-07-13 02:44:10 xxxxx yyy
   #5 2017-07-13 02:44:11 xxxxx yyy
   #6 2017-07-13 02:44:21 xxxxx yyy
   ```

The output of both code snippets is the same, depending on the system time it got executed.

Comment: @anitasp If you can mark this as the answer, I would highly appreciate it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is speed. The loop executes fast enough to iterate through every row within a single one-second interval, then hangs until the break condition is triggered. As a result, the timestamps are the same.

Remove the call to `Sys.sleep` to recreate the issue (identical timestamps)

```
a <- data.frame(V1 = c("Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
                        "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
                        "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
                        "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
                        "Refierenos alguien que compre o arriende, si concreta obtén un ingreso extra \n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ", 
                        "Menciona a un amigo que quiera comprar una propiedad, si concreta, consigue dinero plus\n\ngoo.gl/OlPYuZ" ), 
                textid = c("xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy", "xxxxx yyy" ), 
                limit = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(a)

df <- NULL
i <- 1

repeat {
    t <- Sys.time()

    if ( as.integer(t) %% 11 & as.integer(t) %% 17 == 0 ) {

        new_row <- a[i, ]
        new_row$id <- paste(t, a$textid[i])

        if ( is.null(df) ) {
            df <- new_row
        } else {
            df <- rbind(df, new_row)
        }

        i <- 1+i

        # Force a pause. Without this the times are all the same
        Sys.sleep(1) 
    }

    if( i > nrow(a) ) break
}

df[, c("id", "textid", "limit")]
```

Result

```
                             id    textid limit
1 2017-07-12 19:49:30 xxxxx yyy xxxxx yyy FALSE
2 2017-07-12 19:49:47 xxxxx yyy xxxxx yyy FALSE
3 2017-07-12 19:50:04 xxxxx yyy xxxxx yyy FALSE
4 2017-07-12 19:50:21 xxxxx yyy xxxxx yyy FALSE
5 2017-07-12 19:50:55 xxxxx yyy xxxxx yyy FALSE
6 2017-07-12 19:51:12 xxxxx yyy xxxxx yyy FALSE
```

To fix the other problem (no rows in the data frame, `df`) I append each new row using `rbind`